# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on specifying 'ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP'

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to have two columns - created_date and updated_date for every table in the DB.
I am trying the following SQL in Oracle, but its not working:

```
create table tmptmp (
  id number(10), 
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE TIMESTAMP
);
```

The above gives the following error:

```
Error at Command Line:5 Column:42
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any clue what is wrong here?

Comment: At a guess I'd say you're missing a parenthesis. Check your syntax.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a syntax error.


Comment: What RDBMS are you using, Oracle or MySQL? If it's Oracle and you want to define a column with default updatable value of timestamp data type then it will be enough to specify only `default current_timestamp`. The `on update current_timestamp` is MySQL syntax.

Comment: I mentioned already that the DB is Oracle.
And I want two columns - created-date (ct) and updated-date(ut). 
That is why ut has some more syntax (On Update current_timestamp).
Is there an equivalent of 'On update Current_Timestamp' in Oracle apart from triggers?

Comment: What made you think Oracle supports an `ON UPDATE` clause? There is nothing like that in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_7002.htm#CEGEDHJE

Comment: The confusion is that MySql documentation is now under Oracle. So if you search for SQL docs under oracle you get MySQL, it has just caught me out too.